# Multiple attribute on href using onclick

Tags: javascript

> I Tried this code to get multiple value in href but it does not work. any problem on this one ?

```
 <a  href=""onclick="this.href='printsales.php?CUSTOMERID='+document.getElementById('CUS_CODE_MX').value'&AGE='+document.getElementById('AGEID').value" target="_blank">Print</a>
```

Comment: Use single quotes inside " (double quotes).

Comment: Don't use inline js for long pieces of code it is going to be tedious to maintain

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing a `+` sign between a string and a value.

The error is between this two

```
document.getElementById('CUS_CODE_MX').value '&AGE='
```

Correct format

```
document.getElementById('CUS_CODE_MX').value + '&AGE='
```

Every time you join a value and a string, you need a `+` sign

Even if you are joining two strings

> 'Hello'+ 'World'

Pliss avoid long js as an inline atribute. I will recommend you call a function as the `onclick` attribute.

Hope this helps :)

```
<a  href=""onclick="this.href='printsales.php?CUSTOMERID='+document.getElementById('CUS_CODE_MX').value+'&AGE='+document.getElementById('AGEID').value" target="_blank">Print</a>
```

Answer (score 1):

It's better to use external script for that rather than inline format. And just add missing `+` to your code. Also, using variables would clean up the code.

```js
function func() {
  var CUS_CODE_MX = document.getElementById('CUS_CODE_MX').value;
  var AGEID = document.getElementById('AGEID').value;
  this.href = 'printsales.php?CUSTOMERID='+CUS_CODE_MX+'&AGE='+AGEID;
}
```

```html
<a href="" onclick="func()" target="_blank">Print</a>
```

Comment: I agree with this solution. I prefer html in .html, css in .css and js in a .js. But maybe he just needs to add this js. Its a lot easier to just add it inline than make an extra file. Upvote :>